# Vue.JS - How to fetch user's profile picture from Firebase storage?

Tags: firebase, image, vue.js, google-cloud-storage, profile

For more context, I have a Register.vue where new users can upload their profile images and it works perfectly fine with Croppa, the data successfully passes through to the storage and the user's document. However, I can't seem to get around this fetching the image thing to display it on the dashboard/profile.

I tried `<img :src="store.userPicture"  alt="profile pic" class="avatar">` but it just acts lie

Also I imported the store.js file into the Dashboard where the user's doc's info is located.

store.js:

```
export default {
searchTerm: "",
currentUser: null,
displayName: null,
password: null,
progress: "",
userPicture:'',
profile_image: null };
```

Comment: What exactly is in `store.userPicture`? The file name? The URL?

Comment: Except above, you could add how do you imported `store.js`? maybe some small example....